# How to pass latitude and longitude values into the wunderground API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so i managed to get my geolocation and i tested it and it works. I then set longitude and latitude values to a variable as shown below

```
var lat;
var long;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
var lat= position.coords.latitude;
var long=position.coords.longitude;
// $(".data-now").html("latitude: " + lat  + "<br>longitude: " +long );
});
```

so now when i pass these variables long and lat in my API it does not work, here is how i did it

```
$.ajax({
    url :        "//api.wunderground.com/api/8c89bxxxxf56bc94/conditions/q/lat,long.json",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(answer) {
        var location = answer['current_observation']['display_location']['full'];
        var temp_f = answer['current_observation']['temp_f'];
        var temp_c = answer['current_observation']['temp_c'];
        var weather = answer['current_observation']['weather'];
        var icon = answer['current_observation']['icon_url'];
```

any help??

Comment: At what point do you pass the lat/long to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You should concate the variable instead, so the url should be like :

```
"//api.wunderground.com/api/8c89bxxxxf56bc94/conditions/q/"+lat+","+long+".json"
```

**Full code :**

```
var lat;
var long;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        lat= position.coords.latitude;
        long=position.coords.longitude;
});

var url = "//api.wunderground.com/api/8c89bxxxxf56bc94/conditions/q/"+lat+","+long+".json";
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(answer) {

    }
})
```

**NOTE :** The `var` keyword should be removed inside the `if` block (as mentioned by **@Rowland Shaw** in the comment),  since your variables are already defined before the block :

```
var lat= position.coords.latitude;
var long=position.coords.longitude;
```

Should be :

```
lat= position.coords.latitude;
long=position.coords.longitude;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ..and not redclare a new local lat and long variable

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @RowlandShaw but i'm not sure what you mean :(

Comment: In the `if (navigator.gelocation)` block, the latitude and longitude are passed to newly defined `lat`/`long` variables (note the `var`)

Comment: Yes i see now, updated my answer, thanks again for your intervention.